# two-line equation with matrix inside

Tags: equations, align, matrices

I want to get a two-line equation, in which one line is consisted of both variables and matrix. I tried {align} and {matrix} but not working.

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eqk27}
\begin{align}
\bm{\mathrm{w}}^\mathrm{T} \bm{X}^\mathrm{T} & = [w_1, \hspace{0.1cm} w_2, \hspace{0.1cm} cdots, \hspace{0.1cm} w_n] 
\left[
\begin{matrix} 
x_{1,1} & x_{2,1} & \cdots & x_{n,1} \\
x_{1,2} & x_{2,2} & \cdots & x_{n,2} \\
\vdots  & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
x_{1,n} & x_{2,n} & \cdots & x_{n,n} 
\end{matrix}
\right] \\

& = [\sum_{i=1}^{} w_i x_{1,i}, \hspace{0.1cm} \sum_{i=1}^{} w_i x_{2,i}, \hspace{0.1cm} \cdots, \hspace{0.1cm} \sum_{i=1}^{} w_i x_{2,i} ]
\end{align}
\end{equation}
```

[image: snapshot after using {aligned}]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The equation in the second screenshot doesn't fit inside the textblock. Is there a reason for not placing the final row on a separate line, while aligning the two `=` symbols?

Comment: Placing the final one on a new line with alignment is my purpose but I failed to get it.

Comment: Hello, Przemysław Scherwentke, egreg and Mico. Thanks to all you guys giving me answers in different ways. They are all working. The problem is from some previous .tex files of my book chapters. I finally choose Przemysław's answer simply because I can choose only one. Merci bien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot nest `align` inside `equation`. Below is a version with `aligned`. The code need improvements but it is unclear what do you want to obtain with `\bm`, `\hspace`, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\def\bm{}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eqk27}
\begin{aligned}
\bm{\mathrm{w}}^\mathrm{T} \bm{X}^\mathrm{T} & = [w_1, \hspace{0.1cm} w_2, \hspace{0.1cm} \cdots, \hspace{0.1cm} w_n] 
\left[
\begin{matrix} 
x_{1,1} & x_{2,1} & \cdots & x_{n,1} \\
x_{1,2} & x_{2,2} & \cdots & x_{n,2} \\
\vdots  & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
x_{1,n} & x_{2,n} & \cdots & x_{n,n} 
\end{matrix}
\right] \\
%
& = [\sum_{i=1}^{} w_i x_{1,i}, \hspace{0.1cm} \sum_{i=1}^{} w_i x_{2,i}, \hspace{0.1cm} \cdots, \hspace{0.1cm} \sum_{i=1}^{} w_i x_{2,i} ]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. @Przemyslaw Scherwentke
It is compiled but cannot get real two-line. The second part in the {align} simply moves down one line along the right side of the matrix (first part of the {align}).

Comment: @arifle So it should like as in your (fresh) picture?

Comment: Yes, it is :). @Przemyslaw Scherwentke.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want `split` (surely not `align` that cannot be nested in `equation`).

You also want

1. a macro for denoting the transpose,
2. a macro for denoting (column) vectors, and
3. a macro for denoting matrices

so to avoid heavy markup, with the bonus that you can change the whole notation by just modifying the definitions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\TP}{{\mathrm{T}}} % transpose
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\bm{#1}} % matrix

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eqk27}
\begin{split}
\vect{w}^\TP \matr{X}^\TP
  & = \begin{bmatrix} w_1 & w_2 & \dots & w_n \end{bmatrix}
      \begin{bmatrix} 
        x_{1,1} & x_{2,1} & \dots & x_{n,1} \\
        x_{1,2} & x_{2,2} & \dots & x_{n,2} \\
        \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        x_{1,n} & x_{2,n} & \dots & x_{n,n} 
      \end{bmatrix}
  \\[1ex]
  & = \begin{bmatrix}
        \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} w_i x_{1,i} &
        \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} w_i x_{2,i} &
        \dots &
        \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} w_i x_{2,i}
      \end{bmatrix}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @egreg. This works well.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of placing a `matrix` environment inside a `\left\[ ... \right]` construct, just use a `bmatrix` environment; the `b` in `bmatrix` stands for "square **b**racket". Second, since the row vectors are, mathematically speaking, matrices as well and since they're encased in square brackets, just use `bmatrix` environments for them too. (Aside: An advantage of using `bmatrix` environments for row vectors is that you needn't concern yourself with the sizing of the square brackets.) Third, `\bm{\mathrm{w}}` may be stated more simply as `\mathbf{w}`.

Last but not least, you should use either an `aligned` or a `split` environment to (a) split the full expression across two lines and (b) align the equation fragments on the `=` symbols. The `split` environment centers the equation number vertically, while the `aligned` environment lets you choose to place the equation number on the top or bottom line. The output produced by the `aligned` and `split` environments is shown in the following screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}   % for 'aligned', 'split', and 'bmatrix' environments
\begin{document}
\noindent
with \texttt{aligned} environment
\begin{equation}\label{eqk27aligned}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\mathbf{w}^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{X}^\mathrm{T} 
%
&= \begin{bmatrix} 
      w_1 & w_2 & \dots & w_n 
   \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
  x_{11} & x_{21} & \dots & x_{n1} \\
  x_{12} & x_{22} & \dots & x_{n2} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots& \vdots \\
  x_{1n} & x_{2n} & \dots & x_{nn} 
\end{bmatrix} \\[\jot]
%
&= \begin{bmatrix} \,
      \sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i x_{1i} & 
      \sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i x_{2i} & 
      \dots & 
      \sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i x_{ni} 
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\bigskip\noindent
with \texttt{split} environment
\begin{equation}\label{eqk27split}
\begin{split}
\mathbf{w}^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{X}^\mathrm{T} 
%
&= \begin{bmatrix} 
      w_1 & w_2 & \dots & w_n 
   \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
  x_{11} & x_{21} & \dots & x_{n1} \\
  x_{12} & x_{22} & \dots & x_{n2} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots& \vdots \\
  x_{1n} & x_{2n} & \dots & x_{nn} 
\end{bmatrix} \\[\jot]
%
&= \begin{bmatrix} \,
      \sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i x_{1i} & 
      \sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i x_{2i} & 
      \dots & 
      \sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i x_{ni} 
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Compilation issues.

Comment: @arifle - Very sorry, but my mind-reading skills are utterly worthless. I therefore have *no idea* what you mean by the two-word fragment "Compilation issues." Please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry, it is IT word. Latex engine gave compilation errors to this but I did try using {bmatrix} for the solution of @Przemysław Scherwentke and it was still the same. That means {bmatrix} works at least.

Comment: @arifle - You wrote, "Latex engine gave compilation errors". For sure, the code I showed in my answer does not generate "compilation issues". It must be the case that your code does something that's materially different from mine. Unless you report what these differences may be and/or start providing actual details about the "compilation errors" -- remember, my mind-reading skills are worthless -- you can't expect me to provide meaningful advice at this point.

Comment: Yes, I am checking them piece by piece.

Comment: This is clearly a case for `split`.

Comment: @egreg - I've updated my answer to show the outputs produced by both `split` and `aligned`. I guess that what's better depends in part on the main message the author is trying to send (about which the OP sadly hasn't said much). If the main message consists of the entirety of the material shown in both rows of the two-row equation, a `split` environment is best. If the  main message is embodied in the row vector in the second row, an `aligned[b]` solution would be the way to get that message across, right?

Comment: @Mico. Thanks for your answer. I got it yesterday.